# Flexbox child height

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to mark up todo list. I'm trying to set `div.main-tasks` `height` equal to `div.tasks` so the `div.main-tasks` fill entire `div.tasks` and can't figure out how to do this 
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGYqx.png)

I'm using bootsrap 4 flexbox. Please help me to find solution. Thx for advice

Here's codepen https://codepen.io/enoltc/pen/NwLwmO

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wPEYaB

Answer (score 0):

Just add these two rules

```
.tasks{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-top: 80px;
    position :relative;
    }

.tasks-header {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: @EgorNovozhilov Reworked, just alter these two classes.

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
 height:calc(100vh - 80px);
```

on .task div

```
.task {
  margin: 10px 0;
  height:calc(100vh - 80px);
}
```

Comment: or min-height if your content is dynamic and needs dynamic height